# How to hide columns in React-table, specifically with sub-headings?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have searched out the documentation & some blog-posts and found that **setHiddenColumns** is a way to hide columns in React-table, but I've not found any example to understand how could I apply in case of sub-headings as well. In the following example, **show** is not working in React-table@v7.0.4 
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

```
[{
  Header: "SOCIAL MEDIA",
  show: false,
  columns: [{
      Header: "NETWORK SCORE",
      accessor: "social_network_score",
      Cell: (props) => ( <
        CustomCell {
          ...props
        }
        acckey = "social_network_score" />
      ),
    },
    {
      Header: "TWEETS",
      accessor: "total_tweets",
      Cell: (props) => < CustomCell {
        ...props
      }
      acckey = "total_tweets" />
    },
  ],
}]
```

Comment: Check https://react-table.js.org/api/useTable, You need to send initialState object which has hiddenColumns array which contains the accessor of columns.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. But, would it be possible to modify initialState.hiddenColumns dynamically, say as according to my Redux-state?

Comment: Check stateReducers & useControlled State from useTable - https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useTable.md